# Should I include images imitating my web app's interface in the promo website if they're in a different style?

Tags: web-app, landing-page

I'm designing a landing page for my web app, and some of the options I have include pictures that intend to approximately mimic the app's user interface and give the customer an idea of what it looks like. It features some primitive data forms, a couple charts, a logo, etc.

My question is: would it hurt if those images were stylistically different from the actual interface? I'm tempted to say that it's a bad practice, because seeing the interface that's totally unlike the landing page would probably make the user feel cheated. Is this a justified concern, or is such a difference a normal thing to have?

Comment: I think you have answered your own question Alex. It is best to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deal with the same situation where the company has lots of products and lots of documentations for them.

As a broader issue here, **keeping consistency** a.k.a. **adaptivity** within all platforms is desirable to catch more users and making feel them having the same experience with the New product. That makes in your case the product's itself, after the landing page.

Answer (score 1):

I would go through the design brief at first and reconsider where to use an illustration that mimics the application and where to use a different style that features icons, user pictures, arrows, or whatnot.

It's not a problem if your illustrations are a bit different from the app in style, but make sure to use the icons, logos, colors, etc consistently across the page. That way users will feel at home when they start using the application.